# Passing parameter to Java class using scripted DS in Birt

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I have a method `RunReport( rptfile, o/p path, emp_id);`
which generate the report using scripted Data Source. I need to pass `emp_id` to the script

```
Open():             
count = 0;

// Create instance of my class
p= new Packages.joez.sal();

//Load the List
s = p.getSal(emp_id);
```

where based on `emp_id`, the report is generated. Please let me know how to set the value of `emp_id` in Java class from script.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for info. But I have already mentioned that its working with the above solution :) - Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In the script you cite above, you simply need to properly reference the parameter so it can be passed in by value.

Change you call to getSal(...) to look like this:

```
s = p.getSal(params["emp_id"]);
```

That should be the only change you need.

Good Luck!

Comment: Please let me know how to fetch the values of arraylist in Script.



method: public class sal {

 public ArrayList<SalaryVO> getSal(String e) {}}




SCRIPT:

open -
 p= new Packages.joe.birt.action.sal();
  var s=p.getSal(params["emp_id"]);
  


Fetch-
 done=false;
if( s!=null && !done ){
       row["name"] = s.getName();
      row["ID"] = s.getEmpId();
        s=null;
      done=true; 
    }
    return done;